# What can I do to debug memory usage without compiling with profiling?

Tags: haskell, memory, memory-leaks, profiling

Let's say for some reason I can't recompile my program with profiling. What can I do to try to pinpoint the source of memory overconsumption? I've run with RTS `-S`and determined that memory usage is steadily growing beyond what is expected.

Comment: Run under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) ? See also: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24939604/253056).

Comment: Take a look at weigh package: https://www.stackage.org/package/weigh

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot compile your program with profiling enabled? It might be easier to overcome that issue, rather than figuring out a different way of looking for space leaks.

Comment: The main reason I'm running into this is that one of the packages I depend on indirectly (`ghc-heap-view`, IIRC) can't be compiled with profiling.